# Easily accessing the array of captures of a pattern match in a Perl program

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

My question is: How can I easily access the array of a pattern match in a Perl program ? (I know that there are solutions involving split or /.../g, but I am specifically asking for a simple way to access the variables $1, $2, $3, ...

(I think there should be an array, similar to @- and @+, but I can't find it)

Here is what I have so far (solution A involves substr($line, $-[$*], $+[$*] - $-[$*]), and solution B involves eval "\$$*"), but I'd rather access the variables $1, $2, $3 directly as an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = (join '', map { chr($_ + 64) } 1..26) x 10;

my $rstr = '';
$rstr .= '('.('.' x (rand(3) + 2)).')' for 1..rand(15) + 3;

unless ($line =~ m{\A $rstr}xms) {
    die "No match";
}

print $rstr, "\n";

for (1..$#-) {
    printf "A> %3d. -> pos%3d -%3d = '%s'\n", $_,
      $-[$_], $+[$_] - 1, substr($line, $-[$_], $+[$_] - $-[$_]);
}

print "\n";

for (1..$#-) {
    printf "B> %3d. -> pos%3d -%3d = '%s'\n", $_,
      $-[$_], $+[$_] - 1, eval "\$$_";
}
```

Comment: What does "the array of a pattern match" mean? Perhaps you could give a clear example of what you're trying to do and why you can't use `$1`, `$2`, etc., or an array returned by `m/../g`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Perl result of expression may depend on its call context (e.g. scalar context, or array context, or void context). If you assign the value of the operator =~ to an array, that array will contain the values you need.

```
@arr = ('abcd' =~ /(.)(.)(.)(.)/);
```

Here `@arr` will contain exactly `($1, $2, $3, $4)`, i.e. `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`.

Answer (score -1):

As @atycnth has already pointed out, the array your searching for is returned by the regular expression match in a list context.

Here is your code expanded with this method added:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Fake Data
my $fake_data = join '', ( 'A' .. 'Z' ) x 10;

# Build a random Regular Expression
my $pattern = join '', map { '(.{' . int( 2 + rand 3 ) . '})' } ( 1 .. 3 + rand 15 );

if ( my @captures = $fake_data =~ m{\A $pattern}xms ) {
    print "$pattern\nSubstr:\n";

    for ( 1 .. $#- ) {
        printf "%5d. -> pos%3d -%3d = '%s'\n", $_, $-[$_], $+[$_] - 1, substr( $fake_data, $-[$_], $+[$_] - $-[$_] );
    }

    print "\nEval:\n";

    for ( 1 .. $#- ) {
        printf "%5d. -> pos%3d -%3d = '%s'\n", $_, $-[$_], $+[$_] - 1, eval "\$$_";
    }

    print "\nList:\n";

    my $num = 0;
    for my $capture (@captures) {
        $num++;
        printf "%5d. -> pos%3d -%3d = '%s'\n", $num, $-[$num], $+[$num] - 1, $capture;
    }

} else {
    die "No match";
}
```

Outputs:

```
(.{3})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})
Substr:
     1. -> pos  0 -  2 = 'ABC'
     2. -> pos  3 -  6 = 'DEFG'
     3. -> pos  7 - 10 = 'HIJK'
     4. -> pos 11 - 14 = 'LMNO'
     5. -> pos 15 - 17 = 'PQR'
     6. -> pos 18 - 19 = 'ST'
     7. -> pos 20 - 21 = 'UV'
     8. -> pos 22 - 25 = 'WXYZ'
     9. -> pos 26 - 28 = 'ABC'

Eval:
     1. -> pos  0 -  2 = 'ABC'
     2. -> pos  3 -  6 = 'DEFG'
     3. -> pos  7 - 10 = 'HIJK'
     4. -> pos 11 - 14 = 'LMNO'
     5. -> pos 15 - 17 = 'PQR'
     6. -> pos 18 - 19 = 'ST'
     7. -> pos 20 - 21 = 'UV'
     8. -> pos 22 - 25 = 'WXYZ'
     9. -> pos 26 - 28 = 'ABC'

List:
     1. -> pos  0 -  2 = 'ABC'
     2. -> pos  3 -  6 = 'DEFG'
     3. -> pos  7 - 10 = 'HIJK'
     4. -> pos 11 - 14 = 'LMNO'
     5. -> pos 15 - 17 = 'PQR'
     6. -> pos 18 - 19 = 'ST'
     7. -> pos 20 - 21 = 'UV'
     8. -> pos 22 - 25 = 'WXYZ'
     9. -> pos 26 - 28 = 'ABC'
```